# how to read inputs from a file and to write outputs to another file in c++

Tags: c++

Hi
I not good in c
how can i turn my program to read inputs from a file and to write outputs to another file
in c++

Comment: Do you have a write a program? Why not issue a 'cp' system command from the program?

Comment: `program < in_file > out_file` ?

Comment: This is the kind of question where you really need to either [read a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or search first.  [c++ file input](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+file+input) and [c++ file write](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+file+write)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're looking for C++ code. Have a look at [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/), it has nice examples for stream file operations.

Comment: sorry I need answer in c please

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){

 //Open file for reading
 std::ifstream in("input.dat");

 //Open file for writing
 std::ofstream out("output.dat");

 //Temporary buffer for line read from file
 std::string line;

 while(getline(in,line)){//getline removes the newline char
      out<<line<<'\n';   // Appending back newline char  
 }
 return 0;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet589.htm)